# Process Table in Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server.Tabular

Tags: .net, ssas

In SSAS 2014 (ver 12), I was able to process a table with the code:

```
using (Server server = new Server())
{
    Database database = server.Databases.FindByName(databaseName);
    Table table = database.Model.Tables.Find(tableName);
    table.Process(ProcessType.ProcessFull);
}
```

The code references "Microsoft.AnalysisServices" version="11.0.2100.60".

However, in SSAS 2016 (ver 13), the assembly I reference is Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server.Tabular.dll.

There is no longer a Process function in the Table object. How do I process a table in the new library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To process SSAS 2016 databases, I needed to reference "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient" instead, and send a JSON command to the server.

```
public class TabularProcessor
{
    public TabularProcessor(string serverName, string databaseName)
    {
        this.serverName = serverName;
        this.databaseName = databaseName;
        this.adomdProcessor = new AdomdProcessor(serverName);
    }

    private readonly AdomdProcessor adomdProcessor;
    private readonly string serverName;
    private readonly string databaseName;

    public void ProcessTable(string tableName)
    {
        string commandText = @"{
""refresh"": {
""type"": ""full"",
""objects"": [
  {
    ""database"": ""{database}"",
    ""table"": ""{table}""
  }
]
}
}";
        commandText = commandText
            .Replace("{database}", databaseName)
            .Replace("{table}", tableName);

        adomdProcessor.ProcessCommand(commandText);
    }
}

public class AdomdProcessor
{
    private readonly string serverName;

    public AdomdProcessor(string serverName)
    {
        this.serverName = serverName;
    }

    public void ProcessCommand(string commandText)
    {
        AdomdConnection cn = new AdomdConnection("Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=" + serverName);
        cn.Open();
        AdomdCommand cmd;
        cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = commandText;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
    }
}
```